# how to spatialy aggregate netcdf fields in python, CDO, or NCO?

Tags: python, python-xarray, cdo-climate, nco

I want to regrid population data from 0.05 degrees to 0.1 degrees. Because it is population, I should aggregate (sum) population values for resampling data to a coarser resolution. Although I thought that there going to be a simple answer to this question, I did find any yet. I think my question does not need sample data, but you may find the population data from [Gridded Population of the World (GPW), v4](https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-population-density-rev11/data-download).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also duplicate Charlie's conversion approach using cdo, but because your gridbox sizes (before/after) are an integral multiple of each other (i.e. you want to aggregate over a 2x2 pixel square), then it is simpler to directly use the cdo function [gridboxsum](https://code.mpimet.mpg.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-4110002.8.10)

```
 cdo gridboxsum,2,2 in.nc out.nc
```

Answer (score 2):

With NCO you would first convert the population data to an intensive field (population per unit area), then "regrid", then, if you want, convert back to an extensive variable (population), e.g.,

```
ncap2 -s 'pop_per_area=pop/area' in.nc pop_area.nc
ncremap -G latlon=1800,3600 -g dest_grid.nc
ncremap -d dest_grid.nc pop_area.nc out.nc
ncap2 -s 'pop=pop_per_area*area' out.nc pop.nc
```

All commands documented [here](http://nco.sf.net/nco.html). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. That is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `xarray` packages to read the netcdf files, convert the ND xarray data arrays to pandas dataframes. Then use `pandas` to achieve what you need. Then you can convert pandas dataframes back to xarray data arrays and save out as netCDF files. Everything should be straightforward using `xarray`. My only concern is that `xarray` may not work for some netCDF files, which have sub data groups. In those cases, you may need other Python packages to read the netcdf files, like `netCDF`.

Or there is a Python regridding tool called `xESMF`, but I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used NetCDF 4 packages to read NetCDF data, then I used binned_statistic_2d. It is more straightforward than pandas in that in binned_statistic_2d you do not need to apply group by and aggregate functions.